# Can not post in laravel 5 over jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to send a `POST` request over jquery Ajax in Laravel 5.1 application. I got 405 method not allow, I'm search other questions on this forum but not find solution:

My `routes.php`:

```
Route::post('backend/get_subdirectories',  'Backend\FileManagerController@get_subdirectories');
```

The Controller

```
public function get_subdirectories(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

And script

```
var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
console.log(_token); //It work, I can get my token from meta tag
$.post(
            'http://domain.com/backend/get_subdirectories/',
            { _token: _token},
            function () {
                alert("success");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            })
            .always(function () {
                alert("finished");
            });
```

And I got error 405 - Method not allowed

What am I wrong ?

Comment: Is it the slash `/` on the end of the url?

Comment: @Chris: I don't think so

Comment: Have you tried without? And are you trying this request on the same domain?

Comment: What is the output of php artisan route:list ?

Comment: What is the error in your developer tool?

Comment: @KieuDuy Chris is right, it's because of the trailing slash and the fact that it is using the `POST` method... Adding answer to explain :). Remove the trailing slash and you won't have an issue.

Comment: @Chris: You're right, I'm sorry, thank you very much

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@Chris's comment is correct :)

You simply need to remove the `/` from the end of your url. Your ajax request should go to `http://domain.com/backend/get_subdirectories`.

The reason is, because within the `public/.htaccess` file it will 301 redirect all urls with a trailing slash to the same url without one. The code that does it is here:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now the real issue is, the client will preform a GET request to the URL specified by the 301 redirect.

**Wait! Why would it do this???**

Well, we can look to [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) for the answer. It says

> 6.4.2.  301 Moved Permanently
>
> The 301 (Moved Permanently) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future
> references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs.
> Clients with link-editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link
> references to the effective request URI to one or more of the new
> references sent by the server, where possible.
>
> The server SHOULD generate a Location header field in the response
> containing a preferred URI reference for the new permanent URI.  The
> user agent MAY use the Location field value for automatic
> redirection.  The server's response payload usually contains a short
> hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).
>
> ```
>   Note: For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
>   method from POST to GET for the subsequent request.  If this
>   behavior is undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code
>   can be used instead.
> ```
>
> A 301 response is cacheable by default; i.e., unless otherwise
> indicated by the method definition or explicit cache controls (see
> Section 4.2.2 of [RFC7234]).

Now what's interesting is the note at the bottom that specifies that the user agent MAY change the request method from POST to GET. And it seems most user agents from browsers to frameworks, seem to follow that rule.

Comment: Thank you Kirill Fuchs, you are expert