# POST and GET method probles in ajax call in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Here is my problem:

Every ajax request via POST method failed with Error 405 or Error 404. Everything works nice on my local machine. Somehow all my POST ajax request send via GET method.

Here is my **routes.php** (part inside "admin" prefix):

```
Route::post('/addManager/', [
    'as' => 'addmanager',
    'uses' => 'Admin\AdminController@addManager'
]);
```

And part of **action.js** with ajax call:

```
...
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/admin/addManager/",
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
...
```

And here is what i've got in Network tab in Chrome:

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:**mydomain**
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
allow:POST
```

All day long I've trying to solve this problem. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Your instructions are highly conflicting each other, or themselves. "Every ajax request via POST method failed with Error 405 or Error 404. Everything works nice on my local machine. Somehow all my POST ajax request send via GET method." 
1st statement is valid, and then 2nd statement overrule the first statement. And then the 3rd statement, how can you send POST ajax requests via GET method?? :O

Comment: Sorry for confusing with my explanations. Errors I have on remote (VPS) server after deploy. And I've just found solution, and answer for your question how POST could turn into GET. 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found solution in Kirill Fuchs explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35567173/4373200

All I need to do is just remove the / from the end of url. Now it works well as expected.